# Worst runtime of Delaunay triangulation algorithm

Tags: complexity-theory, runtime-analysis

I am a math major without a strong background in theoretical computer science and I have to show that the worst case running time of the Delaunay algorithm is $O(n^2)$, when I know that the expected runtime is $O(n\log n)$. Can someone help me with this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's the problem I dont know how and where to start

Comment: You can start by solving a simpler problem. For instance, perform the worst-case analysis for quick sort.